# Why Unity stops the compilation after some errors?

Tags: c#, compilation, unity-game-engine

If you have code with many errors, Unity will try to compile and will present a few error messages. You fix these errors, it'll try again and present more errors.

It stops compiling after some errors, so the only way to know how many errors you have is to fix them.

Is there a way to tell the compiler to **not** stop the compilation?

I'm working on a project where I have to evaluate the effort to use another target platform, so having all compilation errors displayed when I try to compile in the new platform would help a bit.

Comment: I'm not sure about continuing the compilation, but I don't think the number of compilation errors is a good measure of required effort. Just because you get 300 errors doesn't mean you have to fix 300 problems, nor does it give you any indication of the severity of those errors.

Comment: Erm, what do you want your compiler to do? If there's an error it should automatically detect what's the problem so the rest of the program can make sense and be compiled? If you miss a bracket, there's no point in showing the following 50k errors because everything is interpreted incorrectly and would render fixing the real problem really hazardous.

Comment: @SimonTrewhella I know, it will just show me the classes files I'll have to deal with, I can take a quick look and feel what's about to come.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault well, compilers are more intelligent these days, so I think they can do a better job than that. For example, if you are programming in java and using a good IDE it will show the missed bracket error and any subsequent errors in that file without interpreting everything incorrectly after the missing bracket.

Comment: @Roberto Java is interpreted, C# is compiled. That's not the same.

Comment: @Pierre Java is not interpreted, it is compiled and runs in a Virtual Machine just like C#

Answer (score 1):

**To directly answer you** - Although you can supply Custom Preprocessor Directives, [as documented here](http://docs.unity3d.com/351/Documentation/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html), there is not a way to tell the Unity3D compiler to keep compiling if it encounters critical errors.

Comment: Actually there's a way to set compilation flags in Unity, for example if you want to use the `-unsafe` flag you can add a *Assets/smcs.rsp* file with `-unsafe` inside it.

Comment: Oh cool. That I did not know. I have modified my answer to include your information.

Comment: Do you know where I can find more info about what makes a C# compiler stop on error? I couldn't find anything. I ask this because, to me, looks like Unity stops compilation after some errors, even if they are not critical. For example, delete a namespace inclusion in many files, it will stop compilation after some errors. It's not a critical error, otherwise it would stop at the first lack of namespace reference.

Comment: Unity3D uses C# Mono to compile, so maybe google around that.